# Growth rate order in Algorithms analysis

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Order the following functions by asymptotic growth rate:

`1) 4nlogn+2n.`

`2) 2^10.`

`3) 2^logn.`

`4) 3n+100logn.`

`5) 4n.`

`6) 2^n.`

`7) n^2 + 10n.`

`8) n^3.`

`9) nlogn.`

Comment: 6 > 8 > 7 > 1 > 9 > 5 > 4 > 3 > 2. I suggest you to first sort them on basis of whether it has exponential growth or power growth or logarithmic. For beginners use https://www.desmos.com/calculator/auubsajefh

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really a programming question.  Either general math or CS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort by order. In general functions increase in running time in the following order:
Constant, linear, Nlog(N), quadratic, polynomial, exponential.

Look at the dominating factor of the equation.

In increasing order:

2^10 (constant)

4n (linear)

3n + 100log(n) (linear but with extra log term)

nlog(n)

4nLog(n) + 2n

n^2 + 10n (polynomial)

2^log(n)

n^3

2^n

Comment: 2^log(n) won't be greater than n^3. 2^log(n) <= n. Given log base is always a positive integer.

Comment: shouldn't we place 2^logn after n^3, as it is exponential and also logn<n ?

Comment: Congratulations, you managed to accept the only wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the dominating part, e.g. if you have f1(n) + f2(n) then you can take the limit of abs(f1(n)/f2(n)) n towards infinity, if the result is 0 then f2 is dominating and if it goes to infinity then f1 is dominating.

1. O(1): 2)
2. O(n): 3), 4), 5)
3. O(nlogn): 1), 9)
4. O(n^2): 7)
5. O(n^3): 8)
6. O(2^n): 6)

Answer (score 0):

> 6 > 8 > 7 > 1 > 9 > 5 > 4 > 3 > 2.

I suggest you to first sort them on basis of whether it has exponential growth or power growth or logarithmic. For beginners use  [link](http://desmos.com/calculator/auubsajefh)

Also have an understanding of logarithms.